# SQL UPDATE statement always updates first row in table Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two check boxes where the user has to select an option from both. They then click a button that updates the table using the information they provided. It updates using the selected info perfectly fine, but it always updates the first row of the table for some reason and I can't understand why. List 19 holds the order number, which is in the form of a string. All these strings are of the form xxxx-xx, where the x's are numbers. List29 holds one of five string options, which are the same 5 options for the field [OrderStatus]. Here's my code for the button.

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
Dim x, y, z As String
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
x = List19.Value
y = List29.Value
z = "UPDATE orders SET [OrderStatus] = " & Chr$(34) & y & Chr$(34) & " WHERE [OrderNumber] = " & Chr$(34) & x & Chr$(34) & ";"
db.Execute z
```

[I ran the code and added a message box that displays what the update statement is and this is the what I got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNDV6.png)

Comment: You should post a little more data, like what is in List19 and List29

Comment: I edited to add more information, but if you look at the picture I posted the strings in the boxes to the right of the message box appear in my SQL statement, but no matter what order number i pick, it always updates the first row entry as well.

Comment: Tip: You don't need `& Chr$(34) &` - you can use use single-quotes directly. You should also be using parameters instead of concatenating strings to form SQL because otherwise you'll open yourself to SQL-injection attacks - or find that strings that contain quotes, like `"O'Reilly"` cause things to break.

Comment: This may sound weird, but are you certain that it isn't working? It looks like you're using a sub-form, but you aren't requerying the form, so you would likely not be seeing the current info, if I am not mistaken. Also, is `orders` the table we are looking at in the screen cap?

Comment: @Jiggles32 The subform is independent of the check boxes and the button, it is just used to search using the search box in the top left. It does show the orders table though, which only has those 5 entries. The subform re-updates when I click on it so I'm certain that it isn't working. The changes are also saved when I go look at the options table.

Comment: Well, based on what I am seeing, and what you've explained, everything looks correct to me. The Query posts back correctly for what you're trying to do (assuming you pulled that msgbox from `z`). I would assume the query would either do nothing or do what you'd expect. It should **definitely** not be updating an incorrect row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out List29 was bound to [OrderStatus] from the orders table, the control source was [OrderStatus], not quite sure if they are the same thing. I removed the control source and it stopped updating the first row unwantedly. Thanks to everybody for trying to help.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. +1 from me.